# Bindparam foreach loop

Tags: php, pdo

I've an problem with mine for each loop. I've created an for each loop for my PDO bindparams.

```
$query = 'UPDATE user_info SET ';

foreach ($userInfo as $column => $value) {  

    if($value === end($userInfo)) {
        $query .= $column . ' = :' . $column . '';
    }else{
        $query .= $column . ' = :' . $column . ', ';
    }

}
$query .= ' WHERE id = :id';

$sql = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sql->bindParam(':id', $userInfoId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
foreach ($userInfo as $column => $value) {
    $sql->bindParam(':' . $column, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$sql->execute();
```

But i think that after every loop h'll execute the query, so of the array i can get only the last result in my DB.

What i have:

```
'foo' => 'bar', 'something' => 'result'
```

What i get as result:

```
'foo' => 'result', 'something' => 'result'
```

What i want as result:

```
$sql->bindParam(':' . 'foo', 'bar', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->bindParam(':' . 'somthing', 'result', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: add some more info about this result.. `'1' => '2', '2' => '2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This unexpected behavior is caused due to the internal working of `bindParam()` the `bindParam($param,$variable,...)` .

According to PHP Documentation

> the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.

So here is your answer as bindParam evaluate the value when execute() is called not like the bindValue which called immediately and bind the values. This is why when your foreach loop ends the **$variable reference** contain the "result" value at its memory address and bindParam then look for this reference and find "result" value because of both the bindParam(...); methods have the same reference, they point to the same value "result" and this get stored in database. This may be kind of a bug for some reasons or advantage for some other reasons.

Now what to do to resolve it? The simplest way is, use:

```
bindValue(...);
```

Another typical way is pass the reference in foreach such as:

```
foreach($userInfo as $column => &$value)
//notice: In this way you also need to unset the $value.
```

and all other things will remain same.However, I will suggest you the first way to do this task.